# How to apply changes of the repository permissions in gitolite?

Tags: gitolite

write access was added in gitolite.conf By push is error "DENIED by fallthru<>(or you mis-spelled the reponame)"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, plese try to add a few more details to your question and maybe include a `gitolite.conf` and the state the exact commands that are failing excerpt

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone /push in gitolite-admin repo